# Use JQuery UI Datepicker with Icons from Jquery UI Theme

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I have a datepicker control setup using the JQuery UI, I am also using the JQuery UI themes which provide a bunch of default icons that I want to use.

The DatePicker allows for specifying a specific image, i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#DateFrom").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/ui-icon-calendar.png' });
  });
</script>
```

To display an icon from the icon set you use something like:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span>
```

Is there an easy to integrate the two or do I just need to hack out the styles/images manually?

Comment: I'd like this, too; I submitted a ticket http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5081

Comment: My ticket was marked Wont-Fix with a comment indicating the the buttn support may be dropped entirely in the future... I guess you're on your own :/

Comment: You can also try to connect datepicker by following code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082204/how-to-display-jquery-datepicker-on-link-click

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to do that manually. By default, the Datepicker plugin uses the following HTML to insert the specified `buttonImage`:

```
<img title="..." alt="..." src="images/ui-icon-calendar.png" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">
```

By the way, you might want to use...

```
$(function() {
 // your code here
});
```

...instead of...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // your code here
});
```

Comment: Why would use use "$(function() {" instead of "$(document).ready(function() {
"?

Comment: 1) Because it's shorter. 2) Because it's easier to remember. 3) Because it does exactly the same thing, since it's an alias for `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`.

Comment: Assuming you're not working in an old version, "$(function(){})" isn't available in all versions ;)

Comment: See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger as @Nipun suggests. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT Note that this answer was correct at the time of writing (back in 2009). Things have changed since then.

Comment: @MathiasBynens So what's the right way to make this useful for new folks now that jQuery makes it so easy?

Comment: @RickAndMSFT - I think the right way to do this is in the answer from Loktar - with the addition of text: false to ensure the icon aligns in the centre. The answer from Nipun does not use the jQuery icon set.

Answer (score 29):

I got it working by doing this

```
$("#DateFrom").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button'
}).next('button').button({
    icons: {
        primary: 'ui-icon-calendar'
    }, text:false
});
```

Just modifies the button that it inserts next to your input for the calendar. By default they throw three ellipses in the text, so I remove that as well.

Comment: This answer actually uses the jQuery icons

Comment: And if you want the icon centred in the button use .button({
                icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-calendar' },
                text: false
            })

Comment: This solution still works. Slightly counter-intuitive: the datepicker option "buttonImageOnly: true" must be removed for this trick to work.

Comment: Its funny that this is still working/viable after all these years. My third answer ever given on SO.

Comment: This is great. With new version of JQUI it should be just icon: "ui-icon-calendar". Also good idea to set buttonText: "" on the datepicker otherwise you get "..." in the title which then shows as a hint in most browsers.

Answer (score 27):

I suggest putting the image into the input

```
input.date_picker {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("images/ui-icon-calendar.png");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right: 18px;
  width: 78px;
}
```

Like

[image: date_picker_example]

*I used [this icon](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/X-office-calendar.svg) from the nice [tango icons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Tango_icons) project also available in [png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/X-office-calendar.svg/200px-X-office-calendar.svg.png)*

Advantages:

- Independent from javascript
- Loads instantly with the DOM
- Future date inputs easy to add

Comment: As @Nipup points out this is how jQuery does it http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to;

First use the javascript as you have already used.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#DateFrom").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/ui-icon-calendar.png' });
   });
 </script>
```

Then, add the following css code;

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-trigger
{
        padding:0px;
        padding-left:5px;
        vertical-align:baseline;

        position:relative;
        top:4px;
        height:18px;
}
</style>
```

This css will help you to align the calendar image correctly as you require.

Comment: Again this isn't using the jquery icon set as requested

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor follow on to Evs' answer... (great help and thank you Evs !).

It works in IE8 too, and I added CSS to change the cursor on hover:

```
button.date-picker-button-hidden:hover
{
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

A very good example with the sample code is provided.

Comment: This example uses the datepicker property that lets you specify a specific image. The question asked is how to use the jquery icon set instead.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from and extending Loktar's answer, you could try something like this, note I have only tested this in FF10, but I can't see why it wouldn't work in other browsers.

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({showOn: 'button'})
    .next('button').addClass('date-picker-button-hidden')
    .after($('<span/>')
        .addClass('ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-calendar').addClass('date-picker-icon'));
```

Note that in this example, *date-picker-button-hidden* and *date-picker-icon* are my own classes, since I don't like styling the jQuery CSS classes directly.  Apply the following CSS:

```
span.date-picker-icon
{
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
    left: -16px;
}

button.date-picker-button-hidden
{
    opacity: 0.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is effectively placing a regular jQuery span icon behind the button.  The button is completely see-through / opaque (via the CSS), however because it is still on top of the icon, clicking the icon triggers the button click event.

Comment: I tried this because Loktar's answer aligns the icon to the left of the button. But I found that the position:relative on the span made it disappear off-screen altogether. Perhaps it is reliant on positioning of some ancestor element...Anyway I went back to Loktar's solution and added text: false to the button, and now the icon is centred and the button is using the jQuery-UI theme, so I'm not sure what this solution brings to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I used this jquery code to get a datepicker for a textinput field and a jquery UI icon to work as a image on the datepicker button.

```
// Apply jQuery UI DatePicker to all controls with class = datepicker
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        showWeek: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        buttonImage: "ui-icon-calendar",
        regional: "sv",
        minDate: "-10Y",
        maxDate: "+10Y",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        buttonImageOnly: false,
        showWeekNumber: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "both"

    }).next('button').text('Show calendar').button({ icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-calendar' }, text: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

change: to showOn: "both",//button

```
<input type="text" name="date_from" id="date_from" />        
<input type="text" name="date_to" id="date_to" />

$(function() {
$("#date_from").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showOn: "both",//button
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    showAnim: "slideDown",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#date_to").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showOn: "both",//button
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    showAnim: "slideDown",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
        $("#date_from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wimarbueno/fpT6q/

Answer (score 0):

In going the route of manually setting up a button/icon, you could use this example from [How to combine the jQueryUI DatePicker's Icon Trigger with Bootstrap 3's Input Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444512/how-to-combine-the-jqueryui-datepickers-icon-trigger-with-bootstrap-3s-input-g#answer-19448982) to have a JS click event set the focus on the relevant date input field, thereby triggering the jQueryUI date functionality to appear.

Or, as the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show) states, you can use the `show` method to display the date picker (note that "If the datepicker is attached to an input, the input must be visible for the datepicker to be shown.").

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "show" );`

This allows you to use whatever button/image/icon next to an input field, and be able to click on the button/image/icon to trigger the date functionality for the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding the HTML for my icon button directly into the `buttonText` option and disabling the `buttonImage` option.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    showOn: "both",
    buttonText: '<i class="icon-calendar"></i>',
    dateFormat : "DD, MM d"
});
```