# How to display jquery datepicker on link click?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick, datepicker

I need to show jQuery UI datepicker on link **click**, also when a date is picked change link text to this date, how can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[jQuery UI date picker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) should do the job.

Check out the example using an icon to trigger the picker:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

You can also call the show() method to drop down the picker whenever you need to, e.g...

```
$('#mypicker').datepicker({
      //options
      minDate: '20.04.2012'
      //...
    });
$('#mylink').click(function(){
      $('#mypicker').datepicker('show');
    });
```

To change the link text after a date is selected, use something like this in initialization code:

```
$('#mypicker').datepicker({ onSelect:
    function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#mylink').text(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I'm using this datepicker, but I need it to appear on text link click, not input and not button/image, can't find how to do it.

Comment: How can I call `show()` method? I'm not very good in JavaScript, thanks

Comment: What is `#mypicker` in this case?

Comment: The id of the input element that you initialise as a datepicker. In jQuery examples (follow the links I gave you) it would be '#datepicker'

Comment: I'm trying this code : ` $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  $('#mylink').click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').show();
  });
 })` but it is not working. I have hidden input with `id="datepicker"` and link with `id="mylink"`

Comment: sorry, slight error in my example, I've corrected the answer.  Should have been `$('#mypicker').datepicker('show');`

Comment: Ok, thank you, now it's working, by any chance, do you know how can I change link text after date is picked? thank you anyway.

Comment: I've just added to my answer; you can provide a function when you initialise the datepicker that will run when a date is selected.

Comment: **Don't forget to initialize datepicker** by `$('#mypicker').datepicker({minDate: '20.04.2012', ...})` together with other TheGermanOne's code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dateField").datepicker({
 dateFormat:'dd/M/yy',
 minDate: 'now',
 changeMonth:true,
 changeYear:true,
 showOn: "focus",
 //buttonImage: "YourImage",
 buttonImageOnly: true, 
 yearRange: "-100:+0",  
}); 

$("dateField").datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Needs jquery-ui .ls and .css.

```
 $( function() {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
            $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, may be it's to late to reply in this post, but here is a great [solution from Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12207048/4067532) in a similar thread, which works in 2015.

In a few words you need to put hidden input right after link and an empty div. The last one will do the trick.

Besides, there will no need in link click event.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
$('#dateinterval').click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Salam

**I discover this solotion :**

```
onclick="jQuery('#elementid').datetimepicker();jQuery('#elementid').datetimepicker('show');"
```

And work properly.

Sincerely yours.

Alireza Balvardi