# JQuery UI datepicker triggered from text link

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to setup my css menu so that one of the text links triggers a datepicker calandar to open.  I have stripped everything down to the code below.  The problem I am experiencing is that the code below does not work but when I remove the ul, li tags it starts working.

I am using 1.8.0 JQuery and 1.8.23 JQuery UI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        },
    });

    $("#datep").click(function() {
        $("#dp").datepicker("show");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="datep">Test</a><input type="hidden" id="dp" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Some weird things I have noticed.  If I move the input under the ul it works kind of but will get an error after a few clicks on and off but if I add empty div under that input then it will start working normally it seems.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you use a hidden input element for a datepicker? Use a normal text input and hide it with CSS (display:none).

Comment: Both produce the same results.

Comment: looks like a jQueryUI bug to me

Comment: As @Maksim Vi said below using visibility:hidden; and width:0;border:none; does work where display:none; wasn't for text input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So this is a bug. You'll have to add a block-level element right after the hidden input:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="datep">Test</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="dp" />
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/LE2CG/1/

Comment: Changing it to `type='text'` doesn't help. Try it in the fiddle

Comment: Does the `input` look hidden to you? That was the asker's requirement, which the "working demo" doesn't satisfy.

Comment: I see your point. No need to be a jerk here, you could explain it to us in your comment that by applying `display:none` style to `#dp` will break the datepicker. `visibility:hidden;` works fine, as well as `width:0;border:none;`

Comment: @MaksimVi.: My comment wasn't very nice, I apologize `:-/`. Thanks for the comment

Comment: okies with all this going on `:)` I will upvote you anyways :) lol, you both are awesomely right `:)`

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the help.  I was doing `display:none` when changing to text input so I was still having the issues.  Tried `visibility:hidden;` and that messed up formatting on the page but added `width:0;border:none;` also did correct the look but the calendar was pushed down. Andrew's original solution seemed to work for me, of adding a empty div.  I don't seem to have the offset issues so its working without the `beforeShow`.  Oh I'm using a foundation 3 framework but its looking good so far.

Comment: @Brandon: You're right, it does work without the `beforeShow`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another version **with hidden text:** http://jsfiddle.net/sKXJt/ **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/BhqmY/

This will help for hidden textbox:

- http://forum.jquery.com/topic/attaching-datepicker-to-an-icon-for-a-hidden-input-field
- [Open JQuery Datepicker by clicking on an image w/ no input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112035/open-jquery-datepicker-by-clicking-on-an-image-w-no-input-field)

Hope it will help the cause `:)` I am not sure about the downvote `:)` anyhoo see the version with the hidden text here: http://jsfiddle.net/sKXJt/

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        },
    });

    $('#datep').click(function() {
        $('#dp').datepicker('show');
    });



});​
```

**working image**

[image]

Comment: ...and how does this help? Try hiding the `input` (which is the user's requirement)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker heh cool and you down voted coz of that `:)` cooleos http://forum.jquery.com/topic/attaching-datepicker-to-an-icon-for-a-hidden-input-field

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using this throughout my project, I created a compact jQuery plug-in to do this, and decided to share.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yahermann/xyjhyqma/

HTML:

```
<span class="some-datepicker-class">
  <a href="(some link)" data-date-param="(some date param)">(some initial date)</a>
</span>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('span.some-datepicker-class').datepicker_link();  // see jsfiddle for options
```

The default onSelect handler takes an optional link & date parameter set in the initial HTML. If both are provided, then upon selecting a new date, the plugin will load the provided link and include the selected date as a value to the provided parameter.  Example:

```
<a href="http://example.com" data-date-param="mydate">2018-05-05</a>
```

The initial date 2018-05-05 will be displayed. Upon selecting a new date, the plugin will load the following page: http://example.com?mydate=(new_date)

If this functionality is not desired, just set href="#" and/or provide your own onSelect callback instead.