# How to Popup jQuery Datepicker with Hyperlink

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm creating a website for mobile (using JQuery Mobile) and I need a date picker that opens when a user clicks on a hyperlink. When the user selects a date will it redirect the browser with the date as parameter in query string.

Not sure if it's posible to create it in http://jsfiddle.net/ Cheers

Comment: I'm using the JQuery date picker but it is made to work with input fields so as far as I've figured am I not able to customize it to work as I want. I want it to open the calendar popup when clicking a hyperlink and when I click a date will it redirect the browser with this date as query string (I'd prob will have to do some javascript to achive this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging around and found the answer to my question. Basicly I have to create a hidden input field for the DatePicker so it's not shown for the user. I then have a link that triggers the datepicker on the input field with javascript. The DatePicker has a onSelect event that fires when you choose a date where I can place the redirect code. Source: [JQuery UI datepicker triggered from text link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206793/jquery-ui-datepicker-triggered-from-text-link)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="datep">Test</a>
        <input type="hidden" id="dp" />
        <div></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert(dateText);
        },
        beforeShow: function (event, ui) {
            var $link = $("#datep");
            ui.dpDiv.offset({
                top: $link.offset().top + 10,
                left: $link.offset().left + 10
            });
        }
    });

    $("#datep").click(function() {
        $("#dp").datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the date picker you want: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Here's your code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
         $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });


    function ajaxSubmit(){
         alert('Ajax submission script goes here')   
    };
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/resources/demos/style.css" />

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onblur='ajaxSubmit();' /></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As said I'm already using the JQuery datepicker :). The issue is that this is made to be used with input field and not my needs as I want it to popup when clicking a link and when you click a date will it take the date you've choosen and redirect the user to another site with this date as parameter in a query string