# jquery datepicker: custom icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i know there's an option in the datepicker for adding a calendar icon, 
but it will only show up AFTER applying the plugin to the textbox.
my question is: how can i use my own icon (which is added by markup)
for triggering the datepicker's textbox?
thanks

Comment: hiya, see here this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802379/use-jquery-ui-datepicker-with-icons-from-jquery-ui-theme few solutions, have a nice one, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think so you can add hidden field here and than using image you may open datepicker.
Like,

```
<input type="hidden" id="datepker" />
```

now use this code,

```
$("#datepker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: '../calender.gif', //your own image path
        buttonImageOnly: true,
});
```

This will not show text box and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually show the datepicker using `.datepicker('show')` (after initialization ). Use the standard `showOn: 'focus'` option for the rest.

See this [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enZSA/) for an example (uses a `button` instead of an image but is the same principle)

Comment: how does this change the icon ?

Comment: See the fiddle, `jQuery` does nothing about the image (in this case button)