# How to combine the jQueryUI DatePicker's Icon Trigger with Bootstrap 3's Input Groups

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQueryUI has a nice [DatePicker with icon trigger](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) (a calendar icon opens the calendar, similar behaviour to Outlook).

On the other hand, [Bootstrap 3's Input Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) are really nice for connecting icons to input fields.

Can the two be combined without rewriting either one?

I have made a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bjornte/FqZ9X/1/). For the «Start Date» the jQueryUI icon trigger is not active. For the «End Date» it is enabled. The DatePicker icon, unfortunately, appears outside of the End Date's Input Group:

So, is it possible to enable the Icon Trigger as part of the Input Group (looking like «Start Date» but behaving like «End Date») without heavy modification?

Main Icon Trigger code:

```
$("#datepicker-end").datepicker({
showOn: "button",
buttonImage: "img/calendar.gif",
buttonImageOnly: true
});
```

Main Input Group code:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" id="datepicker-start" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This page has your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733904/how-can-i-extend-jqueryui-datepicker-to-accept-an-additional-argument

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking around for solutions to a `datepicker` problem I was shocked to see an accepted answer with so many problems (and 10 upvotes). It only works by accidental side-effect.

- It has a DOM ready handler *inside the click event*. This is pointless as it does nothing (or it should at least be outside the click handler)
- It is reinitialising `datepicker` *on every click of the icon*

The corrected version should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker-my").datepicker();
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker-my").focus();
  });
});
```

- Initialise datepicker once only
- Cause focus on the input when the icon is clicked (which fires up the calendar).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/JHBpd/151/

Note: It is preferred nowadays to use the *shortcut DOM ready handler*, so the example would become:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker-my").datepicker();
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#datepicker-my").focus();
  });
});
```

### Update to support multiple controls via class selectors:

Change the HTML to have identifiable classes and change the focus selectors to select the edit box relative to the button (within same input-group).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/JHBpd/260/

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker-my").datepicker();
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $(".datepicker-my", $(this).closest(".input-group")).focus();
  });
});
```

Comment: if i have 2 date picker input, do i initialise them separately?.i mean like a   $("#datepicker-A").datepicker(); and $("#datepicker-B").datepicker(); follow by 2 focus

Comment: @user1166085: Use **class** selectors instead of the **ID** selectors shown and it will work for them all so long as the *focus()* targets an element relative to *this* in the click handler. Added example above

Comment: Great solution!  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 7):

I think that you want to show up jquery ui datepicker on bootstrap icon trigger, if it is so here is the solution. [**Demo JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/JHBpd/)

JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    //alert('clicked');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker-my").datepicker().focus();
    });
});
```

Comment: 10 upvotes on an answer with so many problems is quite impressive. This only works because of an accidental side-effect. This code recreates the datepicker on every button click and has a redundant doc ready handler *inside a click event!* Seriously guys? 10 upvotes? :)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to use `label` tag with `for` attribute to select the input field.

> The HTML Label Element () represents a caption for an item in a user interface. It can be associated with a control either by placing the control element inside the  element, or by using the for attribute.

More details and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

The value of `for` attribute will be the ID of a labelable form-related element, e.g. `input`. In my understand it will focus to your input, since the input already triggers with the date-picker. So, the work is done.

```
 <div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" id="datepicker-start" class="form-control" placeholder="Start Date" />    
   <label class="input-group-addon" for="datepicker-start">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </label>
 </div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/om01kgk5/1/

Comment: Simply the best way!Good idea! +1

Comment: The JSFiddle does not match the example above (e.g. it does not even have a `label` and does not work). Can you update with a working example?

Comment: @AdaroMu: Cutting and pasting *my own* working JSFiddle *exactly* (including my commented out line etc) is not what I had in mind for *your* working answer :) We call that plagiarism. Please accept my `-1` until you add your own answer.

Comment: @GoneCoding Sorry about that, I mistook that as the questioner's jsfiddle. Changed the jsfiddle.

Comment: Better. Works fine. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#checkin").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  minDate: '0',
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1
 });
```

```css
.datedivmng{
    float: left;position: relative;
}
.datedivmng .datepicker{
    position: relative;width: 87%!important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.datedivmng:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f073";
    color: #329ac4;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    pointer-events: none;
    float: right;
    top: 2px;
    right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datedivmng">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" name="checkin"  value="" /></div>
```

Comment: Best to describe what you are doing as well as show the example. Basically, you are overlaying a click-transparent fontawesome calendar icon on top of the edit control. Simple and neat +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Below block will work with bootstrap 4, providing button trigger(not input focut)
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTDiB.png)

```
$(function () {
        $("#searchTextDOB").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",            
            buttonImageOnly: false,
            buttonText: ''
        }).next(".ui-datepicker-trigger").addClass("input-group-text btn-light fa fa-calendar-alt").
            wrapAll('<div class="input-group-append"></div');
    });
```